# Stopping a refresh/redirect on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an app that wants to redirect after submitting and I would like to freeze it after clicking submit. The app is a multiform that has an end slide that I would like the animation to trigger and then freeze it from redirect/refresh.

```
<form id="form" class="msform hs-form stacked hs-custom-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
action="confidential-url" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" novalidate="">

<!-- form stuff -->

</form>

$(".submit").click(function () {
        return true;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have tried adding `onSubmit="return false"` to my `<form>` tag as well as various `e.preventDefault();` methods. All of them will either:

• Cause it to prevent the redirect/refresh but not update the fields in the DB

• Update fields but page will still redirect

EDIT:
After trying to do this in AJAX I found out that I was being blocked out from the external URL, thanks to to r4phG for helping me figure it out!

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will never execute as you've already `return`ed

Comment: @Tushar plus `e` isn't even an argument in their code.

Comment: @Tushar, should I just move it up before the return?

Comment: @j08691 newer to Js, I've only ever seen instances where people use `e` as the argument, I thought it was always a part of the base call, my mistake.

Comment: This is way too unclear. You want to prevent the redirection, but then what ? Send the data to be updated anyway ? If that's the case, follow r4phG's advice and learn Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your submission causing your redirection/ refresh ?

If you have to submit your form to update fields in your database, you'll have to submit your form. But if you don't want to refresh all your page, you should think of using Ajax, as your submission will not refresh your page

Example from jquery ajax doc :

```
$("#form").submit(function() { 
      $.ajax({ 
             url:'confidential-url', 
             method:'POST' , 
             data:$(this).serialize() //submits your form information
      }); 
      return false; // prevent the server form submission 
});
```

[jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I don't know anything about Ajax to know how to implement it

Comment: I've updated my answer in order to add the link to jquery's ajax function. If you have difficulties, ask again :)

Comment: Where would I put this? Just in a `<script>` tag? Also, wouldn't it be a POST method? Since that's what it is on the form?

Comment: He is right. A submission in html includes an HTTP Post request that will redirect your user every time. The only way to avoid that is to use an ajax form instead. Ajax doesn't redirect: every time you load comments on fb or load a popup on twitter ajax is used to avoid redirection.

Comment: I guess so. You can put 'POST' instead of 'GET'. You have to adapt it to you problem. And as it's jquery, you have to put it within script tags

Comment: Will using an Ajax form need me to recreate my entire form? or just the submit function around it?

Comment: I think you you should call your ajax function within the onsubmit event of your form and at the end, return false. You can keep your form then.

Comment: Could I do something along the lines of this?

`$("#form").ajaxForm({url: '', type: 'post'});`

Comment: Maybe `$("#form").submit(function() { 
              $.ajax({ 
                    url:'confidential-url', 
                    method:'POST'
              });
              return false;
      });`

Comment: @r4phG This works well to stop the redirect, but still doesn't update the DB, so I'm pretty much back at square 1

Comment: @user4875251 Have you checked the server call worked ? Placing a trace or whatever ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83766/discussion-between-user4875251-and-r4phg).